# Magento - Extending Mass Action Grid Filters ("Select All", "Select None") to Sales > Orders Grid

Tags: sales-order, filter, order-grid, massaction

I am trying to extend the filters on the Sales Order Grid. For example I would like to add "Select Pending", "Select Cancelled" etc filter in the grid.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer, pl check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the select all option you have to overwrite or copy `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php` file with same structure in `code/local` folder

In the `_prepareMassaction()` method there is a line:

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);
```

set this to `true` and you have your select all.